XML user-defined tag turns into raw in Swagger
As far as I know, if we define our XML tag ourselves and then close it properly, it will be recognized as a tag and will not be displayed raw in Swagger. However, why does the following XML code turn into "raw"?
<Team_Player6>
            <br></br>
            <code>PName_Zh   [string]</code> - 選手中文姓名
            <br></br>
            <code>PName_En   [string]</code> - 選手英文姓名
            <br></br>
            <code>PGender   [int]</code> -  性別
            <br></br>
            <code>PPhone   [string]</code> - 手機號碼
            <br></br>
            <code>PBirthday   [string]</code> - 生日
            <br></br>
            <code>PCountry   [string]</code> - 國籍
            <br></br>
            <code>PID   [string]</code> - 帳號
            <br></br>
            <code>TRole   [int]</code> -  角色
            <br></br>
            <code>PReview1   [int]</code> - 選手審核
            <br></br>
            <code>PReview2   [string]</code> - 審核文字
            <br></br>

</Team_Player6>
XML Tag Raw
